# adding list items or nodes in linked list

Tags: c++, sorting, data-structures, linked-list, insert

I try the following c++ code to sort linked list Items while inserting value from the keyboard. Here I want to insert values at the beginning, somewhere in the middle and at the end in one Insertion function using while loop. my focus is only on how to insert and delete by finding the exact position using logical operations. Could you please help me in coding a linked list that can sort while inserting an item in c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct listItem
    {
    //creating a node
    int data;
    struct listItem *next;
    };
//function declaration
bool Initialize(listItem *head);
char menu();
void insertFirst(listItem *&head, listItem *&temp, int item);
void Insert(listItem *&head, listItem *&temp, int item);
void search(listItem *&head, listItem *&temp);
void deleteItem(listItem *&head, listItem *&temp);
void traverse(listItem *curr);

//function definition
bool Initialize(listItem *head)
    {
    //Initialize head and temp value to null
    listItem *head = NULL;
    listItem *temp = NULL;
    }

char menu()
    {
    //menus 
    char choice;
    cout<<"~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n";
    cout<<"        Menu"<<endl;
    cout<<"       ........\n";
    cout<<"1. Add an Item\n";
    cout<<"2. Remove an Item\n";
    cout<<"3. Search an Item\n";
    cout<<"4. Traverse an Item\n";
    cout<<"5. Exit\n";
    cout<<"~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n";

    cin>>choice;
    return choice;
    }
//function to insert items 
void Insert(listItem *&head, listItem *&temp, int item)
    {
    // check if the linked list is null
    listItem *curr = new listItem;
    if(head == NULL)
        {
        curr->data = item;
        curr->next =NULL;
        temp = curr;
        head = curr;
        }
        //check if linked list is not empty and chose the right location
        else if(head->data > item)
            {
            curr->data = item;
            curr->next = temp->next;
            temp = curr;
            }
        //check if linked list is not empty and chose the right location
        else if(head->data < item && curr->next != NULL)
            {
            while (curr->data < item)
            curr = curr->next;
            temp->next = curr;
            curr->data = item;
            curr->next = temp;
            temp = curr;
            }
        //check if linked list is not empty and chose the right location
        else if(head->data < item)
            {
            while(head->data < item && curr->next == NULL)
            curr = curr->next;
            curr->data = item;
            curr->next = NULL;
            temp = curr;
            }
        else
            cout<<item<<" is already there!!!\n";
    }

void search(listItem *&head, listItem *&temp)
    {
    cout<<"NO code for searching item"<<endl;
    }
void deleteItem(listItem *&head, listItem *&temp)
    {
    if(Initialize(head))
        cout<<"The list is already Empty\n";
    else if(head == temp)
        {
        delete head;
        head = NULL;
        temp = NULL;
        }
    else
        {
        listItem *curr = new listItem;
        head = head->next;
        delete curr;
        }
    }
void traverse(listItem *curr)
    {
    if(Initialize(curr))
        cout<<"The list is already Empty\n";
    else
        {
        cout<<"The list contains:\n";
        while(curr != NULL)
            {
            cout<<curr->data<<endl;
            curr = curr->next;
            }
        }
    }

int main()
    {

    bool Initialize(head)

    char choice;
    int item;
    do
        {
        choice = menu();
        switch(choice)
            {
            case '1': cout<<"Please enter a number :";
                    cin>>item;
                    Insert(head, temp, item);
                    break;
            case '2': //cout<<"Enter a number to delete :";
                    //cin>>item;
                    deleteItem(head, temp);
                    break;
            case '3': search(head, temp);
                    break; 
            case '4': traverse(head);
                    break;
            default: cout<<"System exit\n";
            }
        }
        while(choice != '5');
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: The best way to figure out linked lists is to visualize the problem. Draw pictures. Draw a lot of pictures. Draw the list. Show all of the interconnections between the nodes. Then with this initial list, draw each step you need in order to perform an operation on the node. For insert, draw all of the steps you need to find your way to the insertion point. Then draw all of the steps as you break the list apart and insert the new node. Take detailed notes of everything you did. These notes become the basis for your code.

Comment: When debugging step through the program and make sure the program does everything the drawings did. If it doesn't, you just found the bug and probably have a good idea what the code needed to do instead.

Comment: Write less code at a time. Write a few lines. Compile. Test. Do not proceed unless you know your foundations are solid. Listen to what the compiler tells you. If you don't understand the messages, ask questions about the messages. Do not ignore the warnings. Warnings tell you that even though the code compiles, it probably doesn't do what you want it to do. If you don't figure out and fix the problem when you first get the warning, you will have to deal with the logic error that results later.

Answer (score 1):

Inserting nodes. First... The code!

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct listItem
    {
    //creating a node
    int data;
    struct listItem *next;
    };

//function to insert items
void Insert(listItem *&head, int item)
    {
    listItem **curr = &head; // start at head
    while (*curr != NULL // while there is a node
            && (*curr)->data <= item ) //  and the node goes before the new node
        {
        curr = &(*curr)->next; // get next node
        }
    *curr = new listItem{item, *curr}; // insert the new node
    }

int main()
    {

    listItem * head = NULL; // empty linked list head

    Insert(head, 1); // test insert to empty list
    Insert(head, 0); // insert at head
    Insert(head, 3); // insert at end
    Insert(head, 2); // insert in the middle
    }
```

I've removed all of the unnecessary code to focus on the insertion logic. You should always do this with a stack overflow question. To keep the noise in the question down, create a simple program that illustrates the problem and does nothing else. Read [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more information and inspiration.

The code is almost self explanatory: Loop through the list until we find where to insert the node and then insert the node, but there are two little tricks.

There's the `head` node and there are `next` nodes. Both do the same job: Point to the next node in the list. Since they have different names, we need different code to deal with them. But what if we could make `head` and all of the `next` nodes have the same name? Then they can have the exact same code. That's `curr`'s job. Now it doesn't matter if `curr` is `head` or a `next`. Most of the function's code just... goes away. And code that doesn't exist has no bugs.

The other problem with inserting into a singly linked list if you iterate to the node you need to insert ahead of, you've lost track of the node before it. To maintain the linkage you have to have the previous node's `next` pointer (or the `head`). You can maintain a pointer to the previous node, but this doesn't work with `head` since there is no `head` node, so you ruin the first trick and wind up with some nearly duplicated code. But if you abstract away the node and and store the address of `head` or the `next` pointer you have two pieces of information in one: The insertion point and the node after the insertion point. With

```
listItem **curr;
```

`curr` points to where we want to place the new node and `*curr` is the node after it. So

```
while (*curr != NULL // while there is a node
        && (*curr)->data <= item ) //  and the node goes before the new node
    {
    curr = &(*curr)->next; // get next node
    }
```

Works through the list until we find either the last node in the list, `*curr` is `NULL`, or the data at `*curr` goes after the node we want to insert, and then

```
*curr = new listItem{item, *curr};
```

creates a new node that is linked to the node that goes after and this new node is assigned to the pointer at the insertion point.

`*curr`, the pointer to the next item in the list, is set to point at a `new` `listItem`, just like any other use of `new`.

The twist is `listItem` is a very simple data structure and can take advantage of [aggregate Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) to initialize the `listItem`'s members. The braces contain the values I want in the new `listItem` in the order they are declared in the structure. The first member variable, `data`, is set to `item` and the second, `next`, set to the current value of `*curr`, the next item in the list.

For a tiny instance of time you'll have `*curr` and the `next` of the new `listItem` pointing at the same `listItem` then the `=` operator updates the `*curr` to point at the newly created `listItem` instead.

Draw it out on a piece of paper and you'll see what's happening.

Comment: user4581301, I thank you for your fast response really I like your coding and ideas. But I didn't understand   *curr = new listItem{item, *curr};

Comment: @Wubie Updated answer to explain that a bit better. I'm going a bit crazy with the pointers because pointers and book-keeping is what the linked list assignment is supposed to teach. After all the pain this assignment brings you'll find you almost never use linked lists in C++, and when you do you almost always use `std::list`, but what you learn about how to manage pointers and dynamic allocations will stick with you for life.

Comment: Yes, I see but how can I get the last list item in your coding. Inserting value at the end without seting the next pointer to NULL.

Comment: @Wubie That's the beauty of this. The value of `*curr` is put in the new node before it's updated to point at the new node. If `*curr` is `NULL`, that's the end of the list and now the new node will be the end of the list and point to `NULL`. If `*curr` points to another node then the new node now points to that other node. if `curr` points to the head node, then the new node becomes the head node and points at the former head node. One rule handles every case.