# What does c++ std::list::front() return with an empty list?

Tags: c++, null, stdlist

If I have the code:

```
struct Test
{
  int x = 10;
};

int main()
{
  std::list<Test> linkedList;
  std::cout << linkedList.front().x << std::endl;
}
---

out -> 0
```

Why do I get 0 for my test.x value? If I change the list to int type, it returns a 0. If I give it a char type, I get nothing (or "").

I am curious how (and why) it happens under the hood. How does it handle returning a value of any type and not exit the program or require a try/catch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`linkedList` is an empty `list`. Calling [`front()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/front) on it leads to [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), means anything is possible.

> Returns a reference to the first element in the container.
>
> Calling front on an empty container is undefined.

Comment: How does one implement this? How do you return "undefined" and not throw some type of error to exit the method being called?

Comment: @AdamJohnston The standard doesn't require anything specified like throwing an error for this case; library implementers could just do anything they like, including doing nothing.

Comment: Note:  A mandatory check for empty is a cost that would have to be paid for all callers to `front`, event hose who know that the list is not empty and should not have to make this test. One of C++'s founding principles is you don't pay for what you don't need. You get great speed, but you also have to watch out.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It just seems bizarre to me. For example, if I didn't check if the list was empty and called front() with list cast as an int, I will get 0 back with no exceptions. Meaning I might accidentally use 0 as a legitimate value somewhere.

Comment: Don't count on getting a zero back. If you're getting a zero right now, that's probably just dumb luck. Tomorrow you could get 42. Or the program could crash. Or order a tactical nuclear strike on Zimbabwe.

Comment: @AdamJohnston: C++ is not a safe language; if you don't follow many of the rules of the language, then bad things will happen.

Comment: @AdamJohnston "*How do you return "undefined"*"- you don't. The quoted text is not saying that calling `front()` on an empty list *returns* undefined. It is saying that the *behavior* of calling `front()` on an empty list is undefined, so it can literally do whatever it wants.

Comment: Ok thank you everyone. I asked this because I made my own stack with a singly linked list for learning and for my "peek" method, I didn't know what to return if there were no nodes on the stack. I just threw an exception... I also saw others use exit(1).

Comment: @AdamJohnston in your own code you can do whatever you want. If you choose to favour safety over speed and are going to check, throwing an exception ([`std::out_of_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range) is what the C++ Standard library uses for cases where it does bounds checks) is more versatile. A user of your list can catch the exception, clean up, and continue or let the exception terminate the program. `exit` simply terminates the program.

Comment: Suggestion: Before you start writing your own linked list, read through some of the stack overflow questions on singly linked lists. This will help you avoid a number of common problems. For example, [the community addition to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22122095/4581301) shows a nifty pointer trick that turns removing a node from a list, a common stumbling block, into a no brainer. This trick can also be used when [inserting a node in an ordered list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59779376/4581301).

Comment: @AdamJohnston exception is a pretty decent solution. As for me in vast majority of cases it is better that `exit(1)`, which I would almost never use for something like a utility function for a collection. The exception approach has one drawback: it may be not always immediately obvious that function can throw. You can also return `std::optional<T>`. "A common use case for optional is the return value of a function that may fail." - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional .