# Inserting at the end in doubly linked list

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

**following is my linked list code...
its not working for some reason. Can someone help me out here?

```
void insertAtTheEnd(node *&head, int data){
    node *newNode= new node(data);
    newNode->data=data;
    node *temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL){
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    temp->next=newNode;
    newNode->next=NULL;
    newNode->prev=temp->next;

}
```

Comment: You have a loop that says `while(temp!=NULL)`. What is `temp` after the loop has terminated?

Comment: Add `while(temp!=nullptr && temp->next!= nullptr)` as loop termination condition. and assign previous node for inserted node as `newNode->prev=temp`. Also you need to consider case when header is null

Answer (score 0):

As you have it coded, `temp` is guaranteed to be NULL when your while loop exits.  Hence, `temp->next=NULL` will crash.

When you probe for a position in the list, you typically need to keep "previous" variable to point to the item before the one you are iterating with.

```
node* temp = head->next;
node* previous = head;

while (temp)
{
    previous = temp;
    temp = temp->next;
}
// when the while loop returns, `previous` is the last element in the list
previous->next = newNode;
newNode->prev = previous;
newNode->next = nullptr;
```

Another case you missing in your code.  When `head` is NULL (empty list), you need to update `head` to be your `newNode`

```
// empty list - return the new node as head
if (head == nullptr)
{
    newNode->next = nullptr;
    newNode->prev = nullptr;
    head = newNode;
    return;
}
```

Comment: And if you want to get a little crazy, the previous pointer can be avoided with a [pointer-to-pointer trick like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59779376/4581301).