# Linked list in c++ adding node at the end of the list

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes, addition, singly-linked-list

I am writing a code which will store elements in linked list, however when i'm adding an element at the end of the list the output is always like this...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApWie.png)
i've already search from many tutorials and copying their code to see if it works on mine but it doesn't..

```
#include <iostream>
#define tab '\t'

using std::endl;

struct node {
    int data;
    node* next;
};

class Linkedlist {
private:
    node* head = new node;

public:
    Linkedlist(){
        head->next = NULL;
    }

    void addStart(int val){
        node* temp = new node;
        temp->data = val;
        temp->next = head;
        head = temp;
    } 
    
    void addEnd(int val){
        node* temp = new node;
        temp->data = val;
        temp->next = NULL;

        node* curr = new node;
        curr = head;
        while(curr->next != NULL){
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        curr->next = temp;
    } 

    void display(){
        if (head == NULL){
            std::cout << endl << "Linked List is EMPTY.";
        } else {
            int i = 1;
            node* curr = new node;
            curr = head;

            std::cout << endl << "The linked list contains..." << endl;
            while(curr->next != NULL){
                std::cout << "Elements " << i << ':' 
                    << tab << curr->data << endl;
                curr = curr->next;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

The Output should be..
Element 1: 1
Element 2: 2
Element 3: 3
Element 4: 4

Comment: `addEnd` never modifies `head`. A default (i.e. empty) list has a `head` that points to a `node` with an indeterminate `data` and a null `next`. You would have noticed this if you hadn't been in such a hurry to test the adding of multiple elements. (Judging by your creation of a new node in `display`, and *two* nodes in `addEnd`, you haven't quite grasped the point of `new`.)

Comment: Note that without proper calls to `delete` this object leaks memory.

Comment: Note: `head` and `next` do the exact same thing. The only difference between them is the name. If you can abstract away the name, you can save a lot of code, and code you don't have to write has no bugs. [Here is an example of how simple inserting an item into a list could be.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59779376/4581301)

Comment: I've noticed that Stack Overflow users often have questions with linked lists. To close this issue a bit, invite everyone to explore the following link: Implementation of a singly linked list in C++ - https://pvs-studio.com/en/blog/terms/6684/

Answer (score 2):

If you use `addEnd` on an empty list, `head` will point to `NULL`. Then, when you do `curr = head`, `curr` is also `NULL`. Then, you do `while (curr->next != NULL)`, which is illegal since `curr` is `NULL`, so `curr->next` points to unknown memory.

You can add a condition checking if `head` is `NULL`:

```
void addEnd(int val) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        this->addStart(val);
        return;
    }
    //the rest of the code
}
```

The above code checks if `head` is `NULL`. If it is, the list is empty, and adding an element to the end of the list is functionally equivalent to adding an element to its start. You can just use `addStart` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Bugs:

1. at addStart() function:

> temp->next = head;
> head = temp;

Problem: This code never kept the last nodes' next as NULL
Solution:
a) declared head as null
b) writing code for 2 different conditions (when the head is NULL and not NULL):

```
 Linkedlist(){
        head= NULL;
    }

    void addStart(int val){
        node* temp = new node;
        temp->data = val;
        
        if(head == NULL){
            head = temp;
            head->next = NULL;
            return;
        }  else {
            temp->next = head;
            head = temp;
            return;
        }

           }
```

2. You didn't display the last node.
   Soln: change while loop condition in display function from

> curr->next != NULL

to

> curr != NULL.

OVERALL CODE:

```
  #include <iostream>
    #define tab '\t'
    
    using std::endl;
    
    struct node {
        int data;
        node* next;
    };
    
    class Linkedlist {
    private:
        node* head = new node ;
        
       
    
    public:
        Linkedlist(){
            head= NULL;
        }
    
        void addStart(int val){
            node* temp = new node;
            temp->data = val;
            
            if(head == NULL){
                head = temp;
                head->next = NULL;
                return;
            }  else {
                temp->next = head;
                head = temp;
                return;
            }
    
               } 
        
        void addEnd(int val){
            node* temp = new node;
            temp->data = val;
            temp->next = NULL;
    
           node* curr = new node;
            curr = head;
    
           
            while(curr->next != NULL){
                curr = curr->next;
             
            }
            curr->next = temp;
           
        } 
    
        void display(){
            if (head == NULL){
                std::cout << endl << "Linked List is EMPTY.";
            } else {
                int i = 1;
                node* curr = new node;
                curr = head;
    
                std::cout << endl << "The linked list contains..." << endl;
                while(curr != NULL){
                    std::cout << "Elements " << i << ':' 
                        << tab << curr->data << endl;
                    curr = curr->next;
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Isn't the `if(head == NULL)` condition unnecessary? With the original code, if `head` was `NULL`, `temp->next = head` would set the `next` property to `NULL`, and `head = temp` would set `head` to the new pointer. Setting `head = temp` and then `head->next = NULL` is the same behavior.

Comment: yeah, you can achieve the result by removing the condition also. Thanks for your suggestion.